# How to firebase deploy only the modified code?

Tags: firebase, web, terminal, firebase-hosting

When pushing from terminal with `firebase deploy` a small change, everything I have on my project is being uploaded to firebase. 
It takes a while to upload to the internet because I have a lot of audio files. Is there a simple way to only push the changes made on my project to firebase servers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy all your media files at [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/).

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that currently.

But if you move your audio files to firebase storage and use it from there when ever necessary, your problem will be solved.